# Prevent Asynchronous javascript function calls(multiple function one after another)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple functions say functionOne,callFunctionTwo,callFunctionThree. 
from functionOne , it has to execute callFunctionTwo(). after that callFunctionThree() has to start .
eg :-

```
function functionOne(mapingid)
{
callFunctionTwo(mapingid);
callFunctionThree(mapingid);
}
```

As javascript is asynchronous, i used setTimeOut() .
like:-

```
function functionOne(mapingid)
{
callFunctionTwo(mapingid);
}
function callFunctionTwo(mapingid)
{
//some code
setTimeout(function () { callFunctionThree(mapingid); }, 100);
}

function callFunctionThree(mapingid)
{
//some code
}
```

this code is working fine some times. 
So how  to implement done(),when(),then() functions to overcome this problem?

Comment: See the docs : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when

Comment: What exactly is asynchronous in your `// some code`? If it is not, there is no point in using promises or timeouts. Please show us that code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery.when().done()` this way:

```
jQuery.when(firstAjax, secondAjax).done(function(firstAjaxdata, secondAjaxdata){
    console.log('firstAjaxdata:::', firstAjaxdata);
    console.log('secondAjaxdata:::', secondAjaxdata);
});
```

where `firstAjax, secondAjax` should be ajax calls.